# Python Convert a list into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list that consists of lists.
Looks something like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],['john','leo','steve','ben','sally'],['22','55','66','11','33'],['blue','green','red','yellow','pink']]
```

I want to convert this into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      1     2     3      4     5
0  john   leo steve    ben sally
1    22    55    66     11    33
2  blue green   red yellow  pink
```

Any suggestions?

I tried to play around with the reshape function, but I can't get it to work.

I also tried looking at [ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 6), indices imply (6, 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185926/valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-1-6-indices-imply-6-6/50186267) but that didn't help either.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(x[1:], columns=x[0])` if x is the list -  or do Dani's solution...same concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

Output:

```
      1      2      3       4      5
0  john    leo  steve     ben  sally
1    22     55     66      11     33
2  blue  green    red  yellow   pink
```

Comment: This is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd


columns, *data = [[1,2,3,4,5],['john','leo','steve','ben','sally'],['22','55','66','11','33'],
                  ['blue','green','red','yellow','pink']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      1      2      3       4      5
0  john    leo  steve     ben  sally
1    22     55     66      11     33
2  blue  green    red  yellow   pink
```