# How to create a DataFrame instance from array of arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have created an array which returns **(6, 20)** as an attribute of the `shape`, like this:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.random.logistic(10, 1, 120)
data = data.reshape(6, 20)
```

instantiate `pandas.DataFrame` from array `data`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

now this is a dataframe created using data values that come from the `numpy` module's distributive function

and return this:

```
          0          1          2          3          4          5   
0   9.602117   9.507674   9.848685   9.215080  11.061676   9.627753   
1  11.702407   9.804924   7.375905  10.784320   8.485818  10.938005   
2   9.628927   9.713187  10.027626  10.653311  11.301493   8.756792   
3  11.229905  12.013172  10.023200   9.211614   7.139757   9.687851   

          6          7         8         9          10         11         12  
0   9.356069  11.483162  8.993130  8.015089   9.808234   9.435853   9.773375   
1  13.422060  10.027434  9.694008  9.677682  10.806266  12.393364   9.479257   
2  10.821846  10.690378  8.321566  9.595122  11.753948  10.021815  10.412572   
3   8.499120   7.352394  9.288662  9.178306  10.073842   9.246110   9.075350   

          13         14         15         16         17         18         19  
0   9.809366   8.502451  11.624395  12.824338   9.729167   8.945258  10.464157  
1   6.698941   9.416421  11.477242   9.622115   6.374589   9.459355  10.435674  
2  11.068721   9.775433   9.447799   8.972052  10.692942  10.978305  10.047067  
3  10.381596  10.968330  11.892766  12.241880   9.980124   7.321942   9.241030
```

when I try to set `columns=list("abcdef")`, I get this error:

```py
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 20), indices imply (6, 6)
```

and my expected output is similar to that shown directly from the `numpy` array. It should contain each column as a `pandas.Series` of lists (or list of lists).

```py
                       a.  
0 [ 6.98467276  9.16242742  6.99065177 11.50834399  9.29697138  7.93926441
   9.05857668  7.13652948 11.01724792 13.31658877  8.63137079  9.5564405
   7.37161153 11.19414704  9.45957466  9.19826796 10.13506672  9.74830158
   9.97456348  8.35217153] 
                        b.
 [10.48249082 11.94030324 12.59080011 10.55695088 12.43071037 11.49568774
  10.03540181 11.08708832 10.24655111  8.17904856 11.04791142  7.30069964
   8.34783674  9.93743588  8.1537666   9.92773204 10.3416315   9.51624921
   9.60124236 11.37511301] 
                        c.
 [ 8.21851024 12.71641524  9.7748047   9.51267978  7.92793378 12.1646706
   9.67236267 10.22201002  9.67197374  9.70551429  7.79209516  9.20295594
   9.26231527  8.04560836 11.0409066   8.63660332  9.18397671  8.17510874
   9.61619671  8.42704322] 
                        d.
 [14.54825819 16.97573893  7.70643136 12.06334323 14.64054726  9.54619595
  10.30686621 12.20487566 10.78492189 12.01011666 10.12405213  8.57057999
  10.41665479  7.85921253 10.15572125  9.20554292 10.03832545  9.43720211
  11.06605713  9.60298514]
```

I have found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185926/valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-1-6-indices-imply-6-6) that looks like my problem but it has not helped me much, also I would use the data in a different way.

Could I assign the lengths of the columns or maybe assign the dimensions of this `Pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: Your list of lists has nothing from `data`. Did you mistakenly copy-paste a different dataset?

Comment: supposed to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I have decided to use a random values from numpy

Comment: Yes, but you should also use the same random values in your expected output to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data has 6 rows and 20 columns. If you want to pass each "row" of the numpy array as a "column" to the DataFrame, you can simply `transpose`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.logistic(10, 1, 120).reshape(6,20).transpose(), 
                  columns=list("abcdef"))
```

###### Edit:

To get the data in a single row, try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("abcdef"), index=[0])
df.iloc[0] = np.random.logistic(10, 1, 120).reshape(6,20).transpose()
```